# Is there a way to get Worksheet from the Cell in Aspose Cells?

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose-cells

I'm looking for something like `myCell.Parent` or `myCell.Worksheet` to get the `Worksheet` object of a `Cell` in Aspose cells for .net. I didn't see any property on the `Cell` class that refers the `Worksheet`. Wondering if there is a way that I missed?

Comment: The cell should be created or referenced from worksheet. There you should know the cell's parent or worksheet.

Comment: I want to write some cool extension methods on the cell. therefore i need also the reference to the Worksheet, but i don't want to pass it as a parameter on the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also asked in the [Aspose Forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/288065/howto-get-the-parent-object-of-a-cell-the-worksheet/showthread.aspx#288065). It's not possible yet, but the added my request as new feature request.

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest versions of Aspose.Cells for .NET (e.g [Aspose.Cells for .NET v5.3.2](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/entry296037.aspx) etc.) now, it is possible to get the parent worksheet from the cell object. You may simply use Cell.Worksheet property.

Answer (score -1):

Convert or cast cell to Range and then you can find the Worksheet property:

```
Excel.Range myRange = (Excel.Range) myCell;
Excel.WorkSheet myWS = null;
if ( myCell != null ) {
   myWS = myRange.WorkSheet;
}
```

Comment: Not in Excel. In aspose cells.